# How to access and loop through an array nested inside an object, which is inside another object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am very new to programming just started learning JS. I have an exercise I'm not sure how to resolve. The task is to count which user has the most skills. Given code is following:

```js
const users = {
  Alex: {
    email: 'alex@alex.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 30
  },
  Asab: {
    email: 'asab@asab.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Redux', 'MongoDB', 'Express', 'React', 'Node'],
    age: 25,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 50
  },
  Brook: {
    email: 'daniel@daniel.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'Redux'],
    age: 30,
    isLoggedIn: true,
    points: 50
  },
  Daniel: {
    email: 'daniel@alex.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Python'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 40
  },
  John: {
    email: 'john@john.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'Redux', 'Node.js'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: true,
    points: 50
  },
  Thomas: {
    email: 'thomas@thomas.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 40
  },
  Paul: {
    email: 'paul@paul.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'MongoDB', 'Express', 'React', 'Node'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 40
  }
}
```

I guess I need to use a loop, however, not sure how I access the skills array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you can use a loop over the keys of your `users` object. Then compare the lengths of the `skills` property to find which user has the longest list:

```js
const users = {Alex: {email: 'alex@alex.com',skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'],age: 20,isLoggedIn: false,points: 30},Asab: {email: 'asab@asab.com',skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Redux', 'MongoDB', 'Express', 'React', 'Node'],age: 25,isLoggedIn: false,points: 50},Brook: {email: 'daniel@daniel.com',skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'Redux'],age: 30,isLoggedIn: true,points: 50},Daniel: {email: 'daniel@alex.com',skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Python'],age: 20,isLoggedIn: false,points: 40},John: {email: 'john@john.com',skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'Redux', 'Node.js'],age: 20,isLoggedIn: true,points: 50},Thomas: {email: 'thomas@thomas.com',skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React'],age: 20,isLoggedIn: false,points: 40},Paul: {email: 'paul@paul.com',skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'MongoDB', 'Express', 'React', 'Node'],age: 20,isLoggedIn: false,points: 40}}

let topUser;
for (let user in users) {
    if (!topUser || users[user].skills.length > users[topUser].skills.length) topUser = user;
}

console.log(topUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far?
Start by looping through users Object, then you can retrieve the skills for each user.

```
for (u in users) {
console.log(u.skills);
}
```